# Testing for equality using == and ===

Tags: php, equals, equality

Using PHP there are two methods to test for equality.  In the case below which method is correct?

```
    settype($var,"integer");
    $var = 1;

    if ($var == 1)
         then return(true);
    else
         return(false);

    if ($var === 1)
         then return(true);
    else
         return(false);
```

They are both comparing for equality to 1.  However the second statement tests if they are identical. 1 is a constant and $var is an integer variable set to a value of 1. Surely ($var == 1) is more correct? Please help me understand, as ($var === 1) is comparing a variable to a constant.

Comment: The `===` is strict comparison.

Comment: The php Docs explain this very well.

Comment: Even constants have a datatype

Answer (score 1):

== compares the values of variables for equality, type casting as necessary. === checks if the two variables are of the same type AND have the same value. For example `1 == "1"` is true but `1 === "1"` is `false`

In your example $var is integer type variable and 1 is an integer type constant. Actually there is no type difference. Constant is not a type in any language it is just a value that is constant(not changeable). Constant may type of integer, double, string etc.

A full explanation of the differences are available in the PHP manual link: http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I understand the nuances of == and ===, however as you say === tests if they have the same value and if they are of the same type. In my example $var is of type integer and 1 is a constant. Therefore the types differ. This is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Yes, `1` is a constant.... it's also an integer.... a constant value of `"1"` would be a string; a constant of `[1]` is an array of integer.... constants have a datatype, just like variables

Comment: Thank you, so === compares the value and the datatype.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said.